# How to set printing page size in LibreOffice application-wide?

Tags: printing, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Seems LibreOffice saves the paper size in a per-document manner. Can I override this and tell LO to print **all** documents in an A4 size?

**Note**: I know I can set a default print size for **newly created** documents, but that's not enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

The post
[How do I change the default page size from letter to A4](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-i-change-the-default-page-size-from-letter-to-a4/63116)
has some advice.

User Hagar_Delest gave this advice:

> Personally, I always disable the feature: Options > Load/Save >
> General and in the Load section, uncheck the Load printer settings
> with the document.
>
> I don’t really see the point of this feature. Especially if in a
> couple of years you’ve changed your printer. You would have to change
> your template and then each document made based on it would ask for
> the update when you open them.

Other advice by user rew relates to using a document template that has
the right page-size:

> - open libreoffice,
> - create a new wirter document.
> - for good measure go to format → page Style and set the page format to A4.
> - then go to file->printer settings-> and set the page size to what you need.
> - then use file->templates->save as template, click “set as default” before saving.

Comment: Thanks, I did all of that. But documents that I receive from my coworkers still contain pagesize information as part of the document file, and so, when I try to print those, papersize is set to Letter by default. That'd be just a minor nuissance, except I'm vision impaired and it's difficult for me to change the page size every time. :(

Comment: There’s no command-line option to do that (LibreOffice command line does not edit files). You might be able to create some macro to invoke and click the dialogs for you. Or perhaps use PyUNO to control LibreOffice from scripts.

Comment: You could convert the documents to .fodt which is a plain XML, then patch the XML (using `sed` or so), and convert it back to .odt (or whatever you normally use).